# How can I create a "swap" function?

Tags: functions, algorithms

If I have two arrays, $A[1:n], B[1:n]$, and both have the same number of not necessarily unique elements, how can I mathematically write a process that swaps the value of each array in this manner: $A[1] \leftrightarrow B[n], A[2] \leftrightarrow B[n-1], ... , A[n] \leftrightarrow B[1]$. At first I thought of creating a function but some elements could have the same value in a set so I thought that is not the right way. Is there a way to write this mathematically?

**EDIT**

Anyway, if anyone's familiar this might help in the context, in the algorithm of reversing an array, a while-loop was used to perform the job and I made my loop-invariant as follows:

**Loop Invariant $I(r)$:** $i = 1 + r, j = n - r,$ and at the start of an iteration, the position of the elements of the array $A$ at range $[i, j]$ are unchanged while elements not part of the range have reversed in order, i.e. the elements in the range $[1,i-1]$ have been transformed by the bijective function $f: A_1[1,i-1] \rightarrow A_2[j+1,n]$ s.t. $f(A_1[1]) = A_2[n], f(A_1[2]) = A_2[n-1], ..., f(A_1[i-1]) = A_2[j+1],$, and the elements in the range $[j+1,n]$ have been transformed by the inverse of $f$, $f'$, s.t. $f'(A_2[j+1]) = A_1[i-1], f'(A_2[j+2]) = A_1[i-2],..., f'(A_2[n]) = A_1[1].$

But the problem is I assume a bijective function to a set with non-unique elements.

Comment: For what purpose would this be? Would it be ok to just describe the process in words?

Comment: I was tasked to create a reverse algorithm of an array of numbers (so $[1,2,3] \rightarrow [3,2,1]$). And the teacher explicitly said to create a mathematical description of the process, not just say that elements swap with each other.

Comment: This information should have been added to the question.

Comment: This just about fits my definition of mathematics, but I think this is more of a programmer's type of problem than a mathematician's. I really think you'll get more useful help on this problem over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Would a permutation matrix suffice?

Comment: I don't know what's a permutation matrix and I've already passed it, thank you anyway. I've already changed my solution, instead of mapping the values of array, I construct a function $f$ that map the indices of $A[1:i-1]$ to $A[j+1:n]$ such that $f(1) = n, f(2) = n-1, ... f(i-1) = j+1$, and I changed the value of the elements in range $[1,i+1]$ by saying, $\forall p \in [1,i+1], A[p] = A[f(p)]$. And I do the same with elements in the range $[j+1, n]$ by using instead the inverse of $f$, $f'$. Do you guys think this is enough?